# Catch a wave, you'll be sittin' on top of the world

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

"OK, stand down...report!"

"Captain Singh! The science section reports we encountered a rogue gravity wave from the Tau Ceti sector. Life support, hull integrity, shields and weapons are nominal. No damage to report. However, Archivist First Class Tshombe would like to speak to you."

"Tshombe, report!"

"Captain! The gravity wave hit right as the computer was creating the crossword for tomorrow's ship newspaper. I've checked all the clues, and they are nominal, but something happened to the grid..."

"RED ALERT!"

---

As you can see Captain Singh takes the daily cryptic VERY seriously. You've been assigned to review tomorrow's cryptic to make sure that it is still solvable...otherwise, it's the mid shift for both of us.

[image: Grid]

[ASCII version here](https://pastebin.com/NRtwJdyV)

**Across**
8. Some wine and the latest of gothic metal for Penny (4)
9. Very specific about electrons & protons? (10)
10. Channel oscillation around extra bands (6)
11. Tended to be slanted (8)
12. Elton originally nicked radical ambisexual clothing from provincial (8)
14. That cast-away takes off at dawn (6)
16. Talk trash about women (4)
17. At last, BBC Four films second special at heart of the city (5)
18. Girl from the Deep South is behind (4)
19. Capri esthete makes offering to cleric (6)
21. A little bit after, closure about that girl is something to be found at the beach (8)
23. How long one lasts around it is questionable (8)
26. Lady Trojan a sainted one who imprisoned emperor (6)
27. Careening car hit me. It was kind of mean (10)
28. Escutcheon installation is a tedious kind of work (4)

**Down**
1. Conflict is over in Escherichia bacterium storage facility (4,6)
2. Barge in, grabbing fifty thousand with a frown (8)
3. Coloring stick made from cow-nose ray and onion-skin (6)
4. Stupid to cut lure swallowed by fish (4)
5. One comic is cracking about the means of production (8)
6. Sinuous wings carry lean birds (6)
7. A symptom of tiredness: becoming way up, then down low (4)
13. Even simple machine moves right to left (5)
15. To go faster, assign crew chiefs to pack box with eggshell wrapping over fragile pedestal (10)
17. Mother's fluid dicing of manioc takes half of time (8)
18. Worries about hair after shaving head (8)
20. Take step to replace Indonesia with Afghanistan for attack from the air (6)
22. Halogen at condenser holds up gas component (6)
24. Indiana University has no limits to language (4)
25. *Knockout* star embracing teal wig (4)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your problem is that

> when your grid was being made, some of its entries were knocked backwards!

The grid:

> [image]

Clue explanations:

> [image]

Some comments on things I didn't quite get:

> 12A: "Elton originally nicked" looked like it should give REG, but that would be a noun, not a clause. "Elton, as originally nicked" would work but I don't see a parsing without the comma and "as".
>
>  14A: I don't quite understand the definition here. "That castaway" seems like it would need to have some context behind it. Is there a reference I'm missing?
>
>  19A: "Makes offering" looks like it should be a hidden word indicator, but the "makes" would be extraneous, as far as I can tell.
>
>  26A: I'm not convinced about the definition here either. "Sainted one who imprisoned emperor" is probably referring to Napoleon's imprisonment on St. Helena. But the island was not "sainted" (or a "who") -- it was named *after* a saint, but is not a saint or person itself.
>
>   4D: It looks like the definition is "stupid", but that's an adjective, and CLOD is a noun. I'm also not quite sure how "to cut lure" gives L -- is "cut" meant to be a first letter indicator?
>
>  I'd also recommend not repeating major parts of wordplay like GAL in 16 and 18A -- it's particularly noticeable because they're close together, and the answers are even anagrams of each other! (Amusingly, 16A can go either way, but the ambiguity doesn't matter because it could be reversed in the grid anyway.)
>
>
>  And to not be too negative, some clues I liked:
>  18D's surface is very natural, and the wordplay is both clever and concise.
>  28A also has a very natural surface - I wouldn't think twice if I saw this as a regular sentence (apart from the uncommon word "escutcheon", but I'm sure for electricians or plumbers this could be normal).

Comment: Yep, that's it. Actually the grid modification is a bit stronger than indicated, but the grid and wordplay explanations are correct. 12A (and to an extent 4D) were the subject of an extensive conversation in chat (https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55008248#55008248). 14A is similar: I used "That cast-away" in the sense of rot13(Gung juvpu unf orra pnfg njnl). 19A: rot13(V nterr "bssrevat" jbhyq pyhr gur fnzr jbeqcynl, ohg "znxrf bssrevat" [nf va, gb tvir sebz barfrys] cebivqrf n fvzvyne jbeqcynl pyhr VZUB, naq znxrf gur fhesnpr jbex zhpu orggre).

Comment: 26A: On me. Enamored with the definition, and tried to stretch it too far. 4D: rot13(fghcvq pna or hfrq nf n abha, "gb" vf gur pbaarpgbe orgjrra qrsvavgvba naq jbeqcynl, naq "phg yher" V vagrecergrq nf "yher juvpu unf orra phg" gb cebivqr "Y"). 16-18A: I see your point, but actually did this on purpose.